# Changing font between forms

Tags: c#

So I have a form called fontsettings that is supposed to set the font of Form1's textbox but it doesn't pass along the data from one form to another. Here's the code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // font family
        if (comboBox1.Equals("Arial"))
        {
            family = "Arial";
        }
        else if (comboBox1.Equals("Calibri")) {
            family = "Calibri";
        }
        if (comboBox2.Equals(1)) {
            size = 1;
        }
        else if (comboBox2.Equals(2)) {
            size = 2;
        }
        if (comboBox3.Equals("Black")) {
            color = "Black";
        }
        else if (comboBox3.Equals("White")) {
            color = "White";
        }

        Form1 form1 = new Form1();
        form1.insertFont(family, size, color);
```

And here is the insertFont method of Form1

```
 public void insertFont(string a, int b, string c)
    {


        if (textBox1.SelectionLength > 0)
        {
            xx = textBox1.SelectedText;
            textBox1.SelectedText = textBox1.SelectedText.Replace(xx, "<font family=\"" + a + "\" size=\"" + b + "\" color=\"" + c + "\">" + xx + "</font>");

        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Paste("<font family=\"" + a + "\" size=\"" + b + "\" color=\"" + c + "\"></font>");
        }
    }
```

Nothing happens, anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint and get an idea of what might be going wrong?

Comment: Add form1.Show() so you can actually see it.

Comment: Form1 is the main form thats open... ^^ Dumb response

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, I am not sure this would work at all, and you can delete this comment or vote it down. You are taking a text in the postback and posting it into the textbox. It should replace the text and give you HTML markup written out, but the textbox itself in the client cannot change the style from the markup. You better off doing it through javascript and CSS, and it's much simpler as well. If you need help with javascript, please provide me with a step by step what you are trying to achieve and i can try to write the correct code for it.

Comment: While Java and CSS would be easier, the point is to be able to do it in HTML. I know how to do it in CSS

Comment: The point isn't to change the textbox font, sorry the title may be slightly misleading, but it is to take data from the fontsettings form and transfer it to the form1. The program i am making is an editor.

Comment: So, you are trying to get Form1 to return the markup for formatting, or already marked-up  text? Oh yeah, and can you paste the code where you move from one form to the other?

Comment: One more thing. Try use Literal control instead of textbox.